# Timer in QT 4.6 ver

Tags: qt, timer, qt4, qt4.6

IS there any possible substitute of Qtimer? that maybe less developed that Qtimer thats found  in 4.7 and above versions, I have QT4.6.3. from which I cannot deviate/move forward from so I wanted to know timers that would be 4.6 qt compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QTimer was available even in Qt 3.x.

However if you need something more simple you can use `QObject::startTimer()` for your object and reimplement the `QObject::timerEvent()` event handler in your class (which must inherit QObject).

Another alternative is to use QBasicTimer.

For more info see (for Qt 4.6): http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/timers.html

Comment: thanks! I'm not able to include the QTimer it says no such file or directory ,what setup I should do for that?

Comment: @Naaz Your installation of Qt is broken, then. Qt 4.6 gives you both `QBasicTimer` and `QTimer`. But, in any case, come on, you can debug this. Look for files named `QTimer*` and `QBasicTimer*` in your Qt installation.

Comment: There's little reason to use `QObject::startTimer` since you need to retain the timer id anyway. That id is encapsulated by `QBasicTimer`, and it's the right thing to use if you want something more lightweight than a `QTimer`. Usually, the following holds: `Q_ASSERT(sizeof(QBasicTimer) == sizeof(int))`.

Comment: @KubaOber okay I was able to locate the QTimer header file but I had to copy it to my headers folder so that its now found and I make the programme successfully!